# Get percentage based on count in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have an index of objects that contains:

- username (nullable)
- status (can be "none", "talking" or "customer")

I need to get the conversion rate of users (per user) based on how many objects that has status "talking" against objects that has status "customer".
And then represent this in a some chart.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Below are the steps to achieve this:

1. Go to kibana `Management` -> `Index Patterns` -> `Create index pattern` and then type the name of your index for e.g `myindex`
2. Go to `Visualize` tab. Click on `+` and select `Pie`. Check this [LINK](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/createvis.html)
3. Select the index name for e.g. `myindex`
4. Click on `Split Slices`. And then select `Terms`. Select `status` in the field section.
5. Click on the bluish green play button which would display `Apply changes` when you hover your mouse

You would now be able to see the pie chart with all the values.

6. Now for only `customer` and `talking`, click on `Add a filter`
7. Select `status` in the field.
8. Select `is one of` operator and then select both `customer` and `talking` values.

You should now be able to see pie chart with only these two values. If you hover the mouse on the pie chart, you would be able to see the `percentages` respectively.

Below is how it appears on my kibana machine where I had three documents whose status as `talking` and two documents with status as `customer`

**Note** In my mapping I've used the `status.keyword` as field of type `keyword` in order to run [Terms Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#CO140-1)

[image]

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: sorry, I guess I didn't explain it well in the question, but it must be also per user

Comment: @Jonathan You mean you'd want a pie chart for a specific user? If not, could you explain a bit more using a sample document/documents as an example.

Comment: it can be any chart. Can you please explain how to get that number per user?

Comment: @Jonathan Could you add a few documents for that particular user, I'm not following you, perhaps few sample documents, if you update in your question, I can help you.